# ODBC e PHP trazendo resultados string com problema de formatação

Tags: php, odbc

Esse é o resultado:
O resultado do nome não tem acento nenhum

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código funciona em minha máquina, mas no servidor da esse problema.

```
 <?php 
 $con1=odbc_connect('***','***','***');
        $sql = "  SELECT *
                  FROM tabela
                  WHERE matricula = 3050";

$res = odbc_exec($con1, $sql);
while (odbc_fetch_row($res)) {
$nome = (odbc_result($res, 'xxx'));
$matricula = (odbc_result($res, 'xxx'));
}

echo 'Nome: '.$nome .'<br>Matricula: '.$matricula;
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver usando

```
$con1=odbc_connect('***','***','***', SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```